# How can you simulate a LATERAL JOIN in MySQL v8 to execute a subquery or join for each row?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have two tables:

```
film  with primary key film_id
actor with primary key actor_id
```

I now want to fill a table `film_actor(film_id, actor_id)` which connects each film to 250 random actors. So each film should have 250 **different** actors.

In PostgreSQL, I would do:

```
insert into film_actor(film_id, actor_id)
select film_id, actor_id
from   film
cross join lateral
(
    select actor_id
    from   actor
    where  film_id is not null -- to force lateral behavior
    order  by random()
    limit  250
) as actor;
```

A PostgreSQL fiddle can be found here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6dc21a3ce3404aaf3f4453e2ee4f863b. As you can see, each film has different actors.

I cannot find support for `LATERAL JOIN`s in MySQL v8. How can you do such constructs in MySQL v8?

A not working MySQL fiddle can be found here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c1fb7df00cf8c73cbcca77752c9ef0d As you can see, each film has the same actors.

Comment: what happens when you use an inner join?

Comment: With a plain inner join, all films will have the same 250 actors AFAIK.

Comment: Can you atleast provide a "little" data example (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for PostgreSQL and MySQL) and output which PostgreSQL is generating..

Comment: A PostgreSQL fiddle can be found here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6dc21a3ce3404aaf3f4453e2ee4f863b As you can see, each film has different actors.

Comment: A not working MySQL fiddle can be found here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c1fb7df00cf8c73cbcca77752c9ef0d As you can see, each film has the same actors.

Comment: I don't think MySql has an equivalent (yet). If so, you might have to do a cursor, and just add your 250 random rows for each film_id. Not pretty, but should work.

Comment: @monty Good idea, I'll give that a try.

Comment: There's a lamentation of the lack of a lateral join in MySql here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195868/using-outer-alias-in-a-subquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rather inefficient method of doing this:

```
insert into film_actor (film_id, actor_id)
    select film_id, actor_id
    from (select f.film_id, a.actor_id,
                 row_number() over (partition by film_id order by rand()) as seeqnum
          from film f cross join
               actor a
         ) fa
    where seqnum <= 250;
```

There is also a method using recursive CTEs, but I think the performance would be even worse.

Comment: That's a neat application of the `row_number()` window function.

Comment: And in Sql Server you'd just use a cross apply: select film_id, actor_id cross apply (select top 250 actor_id from debtors where film_id is not null order by newid()) i

Answer (score 9):

`LATERAL` was added to MySQL in ver 8.0.14.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-14.html#mysqld-8-0-14-sql-syntax
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html

> A derived table cannot normally refer to (depend on) columns of preceding tables in the same FROM clause. As of MySQL 8.0.14, a derived table may be defined as a lateral derived table to specify that such references are permitted.